Cannot deploy to firebase hosting due to 403 error
I have already deployed this project in the past, but now I have limited permissions but I still get permission errors when deploying to firebase even if I already have the firebase hosting admin permission.
Here is the error that I keep on receiving when I run firebase deploy --only hosting from the root folder of my app.
=== Deploying to '{firebase-project-name}'...

i  deploying hosting

Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission 'firebasehosting.sites.update' denied on resource 'projects/-/sites/{firebase-project-name}' (or it may not exist)

I also have the following permissions already assigned to my account

Cloud Functions Admin
Firebase Hosting Admin
Firebase Viewer
Logs Configuration Writer
Secret Manager Secret Accessor
Service Account User
Viewer

I have tried re-authenticating my account, but still the same issue.

I have now resolved this. So the problem was with the permissions I followed this post and asked for the 3 permissions mentioned in the post which are:

Cloud Build Service Account
Firebase Admin
API Keys Admin

